# Heroku Photos stored on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I use my server to store user uploaded pictures. This is great however when I make a change to the code it reflects this and deletes my pictures stored on the server.

```
git push heroku master
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroku's filesystem is read-only so you can't and shouldn't store uploaded files in your dynos.

If you think about it, it makes sense. You can have multiple dynos running your app so you can't guarantee which dyno is receiving the pictures.

Dynos should be stateless anyway, so you can easily scale your application up or down.

The preferred way to do file uploads on Heroku is to use Amazon S3 as outlined in their [DevCenter](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Answer (score 3):

Like leonardoborges Heroku's filesytem is read-only. Since you are using rails you can use a gem like [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) that helps when you are handling images in your app and it is easy to set up with Amazon S3.

Other helpful links
[Carrierwave Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)